# Android 4.2: How to get the Easter Egg, a new daydream, and Developer options?

Tags: settings, 4.2-jelly-bean, daydream, easter-egg

1. How can I get the *Easter Egg* hidden in Android Jelly Bean?
2. How could I use that *Easter Egg* to enable a **hidden daydream** in Android 4.2?
3. How can I enable the **Developer options**, hidden by default in Android 4.2?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. **Jelly Bean Easter egg:**

   - Go to app drawer and open ***Settings***, go to bottom and tap ***About phone***
   - Repeatedly tap ***Android Version*** 3 times: It should open a screen showing your current wallpaper and a red Jelly Bean
   - (This step is optional) Tap the red Jelly Bean once and it will change to a smiling Jelly Bean android head, and the screen will
     show the text

   > Android <4.x version>
   >
   > JELLY BEAN

   [image: 1-1]     [image: 1-2]   [image: 1-3]

   That screen is the Jelly Bean easter egg. But don't close it: it has
   to be open to enable the...
2. **Android 4.2 hidden daydream:**

   - Tap and hold down on the red Jelly Bean for about 1 sec.
   - You'll see an animated screen with lots of colorful Jelly Beans and smiling Jelly Beans, which you can play with, pushing
     ("flinging") them off the screen.

     [image: 2-1]

   In that moment the hidden feature will be enabled: that animated
   screen is known as **BeanFlinger** and from now on it will be
   available (with black background, though) to be selected as one of
   the **Daydreams**. The Daydreams are an Android 4.2 new feature,
   consisting of screensaver apps that can run when your phone or
   tablet is docked or charging ([more info about Daydream](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-daydreams)).

   [image: 2-2] [image: 2-3] [image: 2-4]
3. **Enable developer options** (If you enabled them, but you want to revert this process, see Note 3)

   - Go to app drawer and open ***Settings***
   - Go to bottom and tap ***About phone***
   - Tap repeatedly ***Build number*** 7 times. Starting at 3rd tap, you'll see a toast saying `You are now X steps away from being a developer.`
   - After 7th tap, you should get a toast saying: `You are now a developer!` (If you keep tapping ***Build number***, the toast will change to: `No need, you are already a developer.`)

     [image: 3-1] [image: 3-2] [image: 3-3]
   - The above steps enable the ***Developer options*** screen, disabled by default in 4.2 ([more info](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-dev-options)). From now on, you'll see the ***Developer options*** in ***Settings*** screen.

     [image: 3-4] [image: 3-5]

---

**NOTES:**

1. Tapping the ***Android Version*** in ***About phone*** screen 4 times will do
   the trick too, showing directly the smiling Jelly Bean.
2. In Christmas season, along with the jelly beans, you'll may see a
   wandering **candy cane**! It works in both BeanFlinger easter egg (left image)
   and BeanFlinger daydream (right image).

   [image: N-1] [image: N-2]
3. If you don't need ***Developer options*** you can either turn off the switch in that screen (left image) or clear data from ***Settings*** app (`Settings > Apps > All > Settings`) if what you want is to completely remove the ***Developer options*** entry from ***Settings*** screen (right image).

   [image: N-3] [image: N-4]
4. All of the above work in Android JellyBean 4.3 and Android KitKat 4.4.x too

Comment: The first part also works [in other Android versions](http://www.howtogeek.com/121197/4-hidden-android-easter-eggs-from-gingerbread-to-jelly-bean/). The animation will differ with each version.

Comment: The developer options can be rehidden by going to Settings -> Apps -> All -> Settings and clearing the data. This will only hide the dev options, AFAIK. Other settings like alarms and wifi passwords etc. are still present

Comment: Thanks @raghav-sood, now I can update the answer by adding all the missing screenshots!

Comment: The behavior you specified in item 3 in the first part of your answer is in fact required by the [Android CDD](http://source.android.com/compatibility/android-4.2-cdd.pdf), section 6.2, and is not merely an Easter egg.

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) "The upstream Android implementation hides the Developer Options menu by default, and enables users to launch Developer Options after pressing seven (7) times on the Settings > About Device > Build Number menu item. Device implementations MUST provide a consistent experience for Developer Options. Specifically, device implementations MUST hide Developer Options by default and MUST provide a mechanism to enable Developer Options that is consistent with the upstream Android implementation."

Comment: @DragonLord if you read more carefully, you'll see I never used the expression "Easter Egg" in the item 3, because I'm aware this behavior is not an Easter Egg. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: Understood. I just wanted to make sure it wouldn't lead to confusion, because I (wrongly) thought the OP misunderstood it as a Easter egg.