# Android 4.4: How to get the Easter Egg and unlock the Dessert Case daydream?

Tags: settings, 4.4-kitkat, daydream, easter-egg

Similar to [Android 4.2/4.3 easter eggs](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34697/38289), does 4.4 KitKat have similar or other ones?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### KitKat easter egg

1. Open ***Settings***
2. Hit ***About phone*** at the bottom of the items list.
3. Tap the entry ***Android version*** three times quickly. A big K will appear on your screen.

   [image]
4. Hit it a few times or long-press to continue to a KitKat style Android logo.

   [image]

---

### Dessert Case daydream:

1. Go through steps 1-3 of the above.
2. Long-press (1s) the big K.
3. Long-press (1s) the Android logo.
4. It will open a new daydream 'screensaver'.

   [image]
5. From now on, you can select it as a daydream option in ***Settings*** → ***Display*** → ***Daydream***.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it if you have launchers like nova or holo. Long press home screen to add shortcuts->activities->system ui->dessert case.